# cppunit throws std::bad_alloc after upgrading gcc to 5.4.0

Tags: c++, gcc, gentoo, cppunit

I've recently updated my Gentoo Linux PC with GCC 5.4.0.

I also recompiled all packages depending on gcc (it was mentioned in gcc upgrade guide for gentoo).

Most of programs works well, however my tests, using cppunit, throw std::bad_alloc before starting.

At first I thought there might be a problem with updated version of cppunit, so I downgraded it to previous version, but the problem still exists.

Whenever I start any test, the application immediately throws:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
  what():  std::bad_alloc
```

I started the application in gdb and printed debug backtrace:

```
#0  0x00007ffff545d218 in raise () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007ffff545e69a in abort () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#2  0x00007ffff5d8f18d in __gnu_cxx::__verbose_terminate_handler() () from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/5.4.0/libstdc++.so.6
#3  0x00007ffff5d8d046 in ?? () from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/5.4.0/libstdc++.so.6
#4  0x00007ffff5d8d091 in std::terminate() () from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/5.4.0/libstdc++.so.6
#5  0x00007ffff5d8d297 in __cxa_throw () from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/5.4.0/libstdc++.so.6
#6  0x00007ffff5db5f52 in std::__throw_bad_alloc() () from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/5.4.0/libstdc++.so.6
#7  0x0000000000b2b3ae in __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >::allocate
    (this=0x7fffffffda58, __n=18446741874689290911) at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/5.4.0/include/g++-v5/ext/new_allocator.h:102
#8  0x0000000000b2b1e2 in std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >::allocate (__a=..., __n=18446741874689290911) at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/5.4.0/include/g++-v5/bits/alloc_traits.h:491
#9  0x0000000000b2b09e in std::__cxx1998::_Vector_base<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >::_M_allocate (this=0x7fffffffda58,
    __n=18446741874689290911) at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/5.4.0/include/g++-v5/bits/stl_vector.h:170
#10 0x0000000000b2af71 in std::__cxx1998::_Vector_base<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >::_M_create_storage (this=0x7fffffffda58,
    __n=18446741874689290911) at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/5.4.0/include/g++-v5/bits/stl_vector.h:185
#11 0x0000000000b2acf1 in std::__cxx1998::_Vector_base<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >::_Vector_base (this=0x7fffffffda58,
    __n=18446741874689290911, __a=...) at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/5.4.0/include/g++-v5/bits/stl_vector.h:136
#12 0x0000000000b29c9c in std::__cxx1998::vector<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >::vector (this=0x7fffffffda58,
    __x=std::__cxx1998::vector of length -2199020260704, capacity -2199020259433 = {...}) at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/5.4.0/include/g++-v5/bits/stl_vector.h:320
#13 0x0000000000b29449 in std::__debug::vector<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >::vector (this=0x7fffffffda40)
    at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/5.4.0/include/g++-v5/debug/vector:193
#14 0x0000000000b294ef in CppUnit::TestSuiteBuilderContextBase::TestSuiteBuilderContextBase (this=0x7fffffffda20) at /usr/include/cppunit/extensions/TestSuiteBuilderContext.h:29
#15 0x0000000000b29515 in CppUnit::TestSuiteBuilderContext<Types_Decimal>::TestSuiteBuilderContext (this=0x7fffffffda20, contextBase=...) at /usr/include/cppunit/extensions/TestSuiteBuilderContext.h:106
#16 0x0000000000b28a16 in Types_Decimal::addTestsToSuite (baseContext=...) at ./Tests/../../pCpp/CppUnitTests/Types_Decimal.hpp:10
#17 0x0000000000b28caa in Types_Decimal::suite () at ./Tests/../../pCpp/CppUnitTests/Types_Decimal.hpp:12
#18 0x0000000000b2871f in main () at Types_Decimal.cpp:8
```

There is no problem with test file itself, because I made no changes to it, and lots of test were working for long time.

After looking into stack trace, I'm pretty curious what happened on frame #12: `__x=std::**__cxx1998**::vector of length **-2199020260704**, capacity **-2199020259433** = {...}`
Why there is cxx1998? Both length and capacity looks pretty insane (uninitialized?).

TestSuiteBuilderContext.h:29:

```
void 
TestSuiteBuilderContextBase::addTest( Test *test )
{
  m_suite.addTest( test ); //line 29
}
```

TestSuite.cpp:

```
/// Adds a test to the suite. 
void 
TestSuite::addTest( Test *test )
{ 
  m_tests.push_back( test ); 
}
```

Comment: Since a vector is pretty much self-initializing and maintaining, more likely a bad `this` or memory was overwritten by stack-smashing action or a rogue pointer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with partial solution.

It looks like the compile option:

```
-D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG
```

Was causing the problem. After removing it - tests run succesfully.

Comment: So there are two explanations for your problem. -D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG is incompatible with code not compiled with it as it exchanges the standard library with the debug version. If all your code has been compiled with -D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG (including all c++ libraries that you link against), removing the option will most likely only hide an issue. The debug lib has many additional and useful checks that help to find problems.

Comment: The cppunit itself was compiled as a system package, so most likely without debug version of stl.